# Crystal Reprot empty after setting DataSource from code in IIS 8

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, iis-8

After migration from Windows Server 2008 to 2012 (and IIS8) I have some issues with my Crystal Reports.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Crystal Reports XI.
Most of the reports are reading data directly from the database, for some of them I am setting data source from code:
rpt.SetDataSource(dt)
dt is DataTable with the same name as table used for creating the report it self.

From Visual Studio all of the reports works fine, but when I put them to IIS only reports without explicit DataSource are working (all those that read data from DB).

All of the reports that I am setting DataSource programmatically from code end up either empty, either throw an exception (invalid group condition or column in formula, caused by empty DataSource).

I spent already 2 days trying all kinds of different things, searching all over the internet but could not find any related information.

Comment: Need context. How are you setting `dt` when it does not originate from the database? What does `SetDataSource` do? You need to provide some code.

Comment: @Kjata30, Crystal Reports can connect to the database directly by providing database name and table/view/stored procedure. Then it is possible to use those fields in the report. SetDataSource replaces that DB connection and then CR will read data from passed DataTable instead of trying to connect to the database.